# Using MySQL connector with a constructor

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I need to create a class that contains a constructor function with the mysql cursor.

```
class dqas:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='#########',
                                    database = '#######',
                                    user = '#########', 
                                    password = '#########',
                                    port = '####')
        self.cursor = conn.cursor()

        if conn.is_connected():
                db_Info = conn.get_server_info()
                print(" Conectado ao base de dados MySQL... Servidor MySQL: {} ".format(db_Info))
```

I need to use the cursor in querys that will happen in other functions. 
This code will be used as a module in other code, I need to only let the functions built in this class to have access to the server, but I truly don't know how to create this constructor function.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is a bit unclear, perhaps you can provide a snippet showing the way you intend to use this class/module?

Comment: `conn.cursor()` should be `self.conn.cursor()`

Comment: All the other references to `conn` also need to be `self.conn`.

Comment: That's it @Barmar ! Thanks!

Comment: @bagerard I'm trying to write a module that will be imported in another program. This module will do some data manipulation and then present it to the user, this data is in a server in which I don't want to give acess to the user. So i will only write it in the contructor module and I want it only to be user by my functions. Was I clear?